# Transferring data from range to array deleting the last rows

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to put the information from a worksheet into an array, using:

```
 WBArray = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(end1, 29)).Value
```

But there are a couple of problems: first that the last 2 rows of my original range contain useless data. How could I remove these two rows as I pass them to array? is there a direct method like the one I am using?

Second, that my range starts at row 5, but since it has to go through old files, that number might be different. Is there a way I can make a floating reference, so it changes based on where the data I want begins? (for example, if it starts in row 7).

I already tried looping through each item, but that also does not seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edited after OP's clarifications

you could use this function:

```
Function GetArray(sht As Worksheet) ', uselessRows As Long)
    With sht
        GetArray = .Range(.Columns(1).Find(what:="Identifier", lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues), _
                          .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row - 6, 29)).Value
    End With
End Function
```

and call it in your main sub as:

```
WBArray = GetArray(mySht)
```

where `mySht` is any valid worksheet reference like, for instance `ActiveSheet`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, that would work perfectly for 1 file, but my macro loops through hundreds of workbooks, and each of them as a different starting and ending point. So there is no way to call it at each file.
I am Trying to create a loop, to say that, if the name of that cell is the name I want, then use that cell as my start1.

Comment: your question didn't mention any "hundreds of files" and anyway the function is general. You may want to accept the beat answer to you _original_ question and post a _new_ one with _new_ issues

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should have stated that there would be multiple iterations. But in any case,  if I am running for just one file, is there any way for it to find the location by itself, without having to call the coordinates specifically in the code?

Comment: what are the criteria to find the beginning and ending location for the currently active file?

Comment: The ending will be always 6 rows before the ending in my source file. The beginning will be when the word "Identifier" appears on column A.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
    Sub x()

Dim start1 As Long, end1 As Long, WBArray, r As Range

With ActiveSheet
    Set r = .Columns(1).Find(What:="Identifier", After:=.Cells(.rows.Count,1), LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        start1 = r.Row
        end1 = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 2
        WBArray = .Range(Cells(start1, 1), Cells(end1, 29)).Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Identified not found"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is almost what I want, just a couple of questions:
1 - On the end1 as you defined it, if I change the 2 in the end, can I account for more useless cells) (lets say there are 5 useless rows, could I just put 5)?
2 - For the Start1, the problem is that there is data in those initial rows, but the data I want may start in row 5 or 7 (or any other). If I use UsedRange, won' it be counting the first unnecessary rows?

Comment: Re end1 - yes (but if there is any discernible pattern the code could incorporate it). Re start1-  yes again. How do you distinguish your desired rows from the undesired?

Comment: The first cell in my wanted range has always the same identifier. I am trying something like:
    For Each ActiveCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
    If ActiveSheet.Cells.Name = "Identifier" Then
    start1 = ActiveCell.Row + 1
    Exit For
    End If
    Next Row

Comment: Are you saying the start row is the first row in which the text 'Identifier' is found (in any column or column A)?

Comment: The identifier will always be on row A. It might be A5, A7, or any other. I am trying to create a clause saying that, if that cell on row A has "Identifier" written on it, it should be the begin of my range (start1). SO I am looping through the rows until I find the identifier. I just don't know if I am doing that correctly.

Comment: Many Thanks, I will try that now.